# Software developement and team lead

Tags: software-design, lead

can you suggest some good reading for software development lead, I searched around and found some but they are rather old , do you have any good suggestion like an hands-on / reference book?

I have found those:

[http://www.amazon.com/Leading-Software-Development-Team-successfully/dp/0201675269/ref=pd_ybh_7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201675269)

[http://www.amazon.com/Dynamics-Software-Development-Jim-McCarthy/dp/1556158238/ref=pd_ybh_6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556158238)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first book you listed "Leading a Software Development Team" by Richard Whitehead is a good reference book.  It's organized by questions that you will probably ask yourself.  Also, I have recently read the new book ["Notes to a Software Team Leader"](https://leanpub.com/teamleader) by Roy Osherove which he goes into his experience as a team lead and in the software field.  The last section of the book has advice from team leaders in the industry.  He also has a list of books for [leadership](http://5whys.com/recommended-books/) on his website.